# How to use auto-increment for alpha numeric value in database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am working in a project. In my project database, I have student and trainer. I need to use auto-increment with alpha-numeric for student id and trainer id.
For example:
student id should be automatically incremented as STU1,STU2....
trainer id should be automatically incremented as TRA1,TRA2....
I am using MySQL as my DB.
If it is possible, please give solution for other databases like oracle, Sql server.

Comment: Have you special use of aplphabet infront of ID?

Comment: If all values have the same prefix, then there is no need to actualy store that prefix. You can create a view which applies this logic. In general it's a bad idea to store data that can be (re)generated from the data that is already there.

Comment: thanku for ur answer. Is there any way to rearrange auto-incremented value when we manually delete a particular value from the table. It's like 
student    name
-------    ----
s1          a
s2          b
s3          c
s4          d
Here what i need to know is if i try to delete "s3, c" from this table, will it automatically make next field as "s3,d".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have any built in functionality to handle this.  If the value you want to add on the front of the auto incremented id is always the same, then you should not need it at all and just add it to the front in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT('STU', CAST(student_id AS CHAR)) AS StudentID,
       CONCAT('TRA', CAST(trainer_id AS CHAR)) AS TrainerID
FROM MyTable
```

Otherwise the following would work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  student_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  student_id_adder char(3) not null
  trainer_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  trainer_id_adder char(3) not null
)
```

The SELECT to pull them together might look like the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(student_id_adder, CAST(student_id AS CHAR)) AS StudentID,
       CONCAT(trainer_id_adder, CAST(trainer_id AS CHAR)) AS TrainerID
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanku for your answer. Is there any way to rearrange auto-incremented value when we manually delete a particular value from the table. It's like 
student    name
-------    ----
s1          a
s2          b
s3          c
s4          d
Here what i need to know is if i try to delete "s3, c" from this table, will it automatically make next field as "s3,d".

Comment: No, it will not.  You will have to increment the adder portion yourself.  use a select statement to find the last value used and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different concepts here. The autoincrement feature is for ID based database tables.

You can build a student table where each student gets an ID, which can be a number or something else and will probably be printed in the student card. Such a table would look like this:

**Table student**

- student_card_id
- first_name
- last_name
- ...

  There can be other tables using the student_card_id. Now some people say this is good. Students are identified by their card IDs, and these will never change. They use this natural key as the primary key in the table. Others, however, say that there should be a technical ID for each table, so if one day you decide to use different student numbers (e.g. STUDENT01 instead of STU01), then you would not have to update the code in all referencing tables. You would use an additional technical ID as shown here:

**Table student**

- id
- student_card_id
- first_name
- last_name
- ...

You would use the ID as primary key and should use the auto increment feature with it. So student STU01 may have the technical ID 18654; it just doesn't matter, for it's only a technical reference. The student card will still contain STU01. The student won't even know that their database record has number 18654.

Don't mix these two concepts. Decide whether you want your tables to be ID based or natural key based. In either case you must think of a way to generate the student card numbers. I suggest you write a function for that.

Comment: I want to implement id in the table based on the category. If Admin like to make a specific report for a user, will it possible to differentiate trainer and student based on ID.

Comment: Oops, that's even worse. An ID should just be a technical ID, nothing more. If you want to tell a student from a trainer in your user table then have a user_type in it. Or have two separate tables. Just don't use columns where parts have a separate meaning as in your example where the first three letters contain certain information. Look up database normalization: 1. normal form: Each attribute contains only *atomic* values.